# How to refresh the ssrs dropdown parameters based on other dropdown parameters

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, msbi

In my SSRS report there are 6 parameters.In the attached image when i select the parameter TeamName, child teams are automatically getting refreshed in Team Child Parent dropdown.

What i want is when i select the Include child Org dropdown options  then also the dropdown Team Child Parent should get refresh?

Can anybody please guide?

Below is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: You can add both parameters `TeamName` and `Include Child Org` to the `Team Child parent` query to get only the related values. Share the query that populates `Team Child parent` parameter in order to help you.

Comment: Thanks alejandro zuleta!it worked..